# A node having itself in its adjacency list

Tags: c, graph, linked-list, adjacency-list

```
typedef struct vertex{
    int num;
    struct vertex *next;
} Vertex;

Vertex *adj[1];

void buildList(){
    Vertex *v=NULL;
    Vertex *t=NULL;

    v = malloc(1*sizeof(*v));
    v->num = 1;
    adj[0] = v;  //a NODE with value 1
    t = v;

    v = malloc(1*sizeof(*v));
    v->num = 1;
    t->next = v; // and ANOTHER NODE but it should be the SAME NODE with the above one
    t = v;


    //v = malloc(1*sizeof(*v));
    //v->num = 1;
    //t->next = adj[0]; // causes infinite loop...
    //t = v;
}
```

The expected output is a node with value 1 having itself in its adjacency list, an output like 1 -> 1.

Here my problem is it looks like I have two different nodes. When I made a change on one of them the other doesn't change, acting like an another node.

For instance after building the list if I change the value of the node I should get an output like 3 -> 3. But I get 3 -> 1. The change on the node doesn't affect the other one. When I try to point adj[0] to t->next however I get an infinite loop...

Comment: unrelated to your question, but shouldn't you `malloc(sizeof(Vertex))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want. If you want a `Vertex` pointing to itself, it's simply

```
void buildList(){
    adj[0] = malloc(1*sizeof(*adj[0])); // allocate memory for one Vertex
    if (adj[0] == NULL){
        perror("Allocation of Vertex failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // adj[0] contains the adress of a Vertex
    // set the num of the Vertex
    adj[0]->num = 1;
    // set the next pointer of the Vertex to its address
    adj[0]->next = adj[0];
}
```

Can you clarify in what way this is not what you want?

Comment: after setting adj[0]->next->next = NULL; it causes segmentation errors since the last element should be null.

Comment: @thetux4 since `adj[0]->next` is `adj[0]`, setting `adj[0]->next->next = NULL` is setting `adj[0]->next = NULL`, so from that moment on you can't dereference `adj[0]->next` anymore, of course. But wasn't the point to have a `Vertex` pointing to itself as successor? Then _there is no last element_, because you have a cycle.

Comment: Hımm thats right, I got it. I was printing elements until a NULL is reached, thats why I tried to set it NULL. At this point, how can I detect the end of list then?

Comment: If you know your cycle has length one, `do{...}while(curr->next != curr);`. Otherwise, you'd have to keep track of the total length or the nodes you have already seen to know when to stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can verily expect that output all you want, but that's not going to make it happen.

You are quite clearly creating two nodes, confusingly reusing `v` to do so.

I'm not entirely certain as to what you are trying to do; but cleaning up the code to eliminate the two lines reading `t = v;` will probably clarify what is happening for you.

If you want `v->next` to point to itself, you need to make it do that. If you want one node, you must structure your code such that `malloc()` is called exactly once.

Keep in mind that `Vertex *v;` doesn't declare a vertex; it declares a pointer to a vertex.

Comment: Well, I wonder how should I make a list with having just one node. 1 the original, and the other one copy of it, not another node.

Comment: @thetux4: In C there is no concept of "a copy". Either the two nodes are the same, or they aren't.

Comment: That makes sense. But if I dont create another node, how am i going to add it into the list?

Comment: @thetux4: The list can have however many pointers to the same vertex as you please.

Answer (score 1):

you should provide the entire code, to see how you use the function and the list. The actual error is probably elsewhere. 
How do you compare if the end of the list is reached?

Usually the `next` pointer of the last node of a linked list is assigned `NULL`. This would be less likely to cause infinite loops.

---

normally you would do something like this:

```
void buildList(){
  // the list base
  adj[0] = malloc(1*sizeof(*v));
  adj[0]->num = 1;
  adj[0]->next = adj[0]; // <-- make the last node point to itself

  // append more items to the end of the list
  Vertex *v=adj[0];
  while (v != v->next) v = v->next; // <-- find the end of the list
  int i;
  int num_nodes = 1; // <-- specify the number of nodes you want in total
  for (i = 1; i < num_nodes; i++) {
    // append another item
    v->next = malloc(1*sizeof(*v)); 
    // initialize it
    v = v->next;
    v->num = i; 
    v->next = v; // <-- make the last node point to itself
  }
}
```

whereas the infinite loop you describe probably comes from the fact that you assigned the list base to the end of the list. Thus effectively making the list a cycle.

Comment: Well I put t = NULL at the very end. But its not changing anything.

Comment: I mean `t->next = NULL;`. But this depends on how you actually traverse the linked list, i.e. how you detect whether the end of the list has been reached.

Comment: well i check if the next one is null or not.

Comment: Well your code works as well but not solving my problem. 
After your code the output is like : 1 -> 1,2 right? but it creates 3 different nodes! 1 and other 1 are different nodes.

Comment: simply adjust the conditional of the loop (`num_nodes`) to specify the number of nodes produced. I don't know what your program will actually put out in the end.

Comment: Its not related with num_nodes. I only want to have just 1 node having itself in its list. Output should be 1(the actuall node) ->(having list) 1(copy of the original)
I dont need two different nodes.

Comment: you mean something like `v->next = v` ?

Comment: Whats the point of finding the last element? Last node should be null actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can analyse the code snippet as follows:

  You are allocating pointer v by mallocing it. and assigning it a value of 1 .Note that the pointer to point to the next element ,v->next is uninitialized

  Then you copy v to adj[0] and t. And re-initialization of v again occurs, (which i think is redundant) , set its value and copy its value to t->next

  So far you have got t to point to itself ie 1 points to 1 .But when you again re-initialization t to v again , v which has v->next un-initialized causes t-> next to also be un-initialized thus the variable pointing to iyself is now not possible

  In the commented part of the code the same thing occurs as adj[0] is v .So regarding the infinite loop it is due to the usage of the above snippet in your work ,which when run separately will give you a segmentation error on accessing t->next

Answer (score 0):

The code that has been put up looks like its just creating 2 separate nodes, and later your just reassigning the node t=v, which make the pointer to point to only one node.

the back up of node 1, on array is not that clear and the reasons behind them.

it would be good if u can explain the logic that your trying to achieve.